# PostgreSQL Between clause

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have this sample statement here:

```
WHERE e.modified_date::DATE between '2013-04-02'::DATE
AND '2013-04-02'::DATE
```

Note:
Those dates were actually variables.

In pgAdmin, running this will result to this sample table:

```
username  modified_date
Sample     2013-04-02
Sample1    2013-04-02
```

This is my desired result.

However, calling the proc from Java would result to nothing. Changing the second date will return the previous sample table. It seems that PostgreSQL is evaluating the date if it is less than the second variable. Am I missing something?
Note: `modified_date` is `timestamp`

Comment: Please show the code you are having a problem with. If it's Java code, show a self-contained Java class demonstrating the problem. Also include your PgJDBC and PostgreSQL versions and the contents of your PostgreSQL error log after running the test program.

Comment: Craig Ringer, thanks for dropping by and sorry for spending your time. I was able to fix the problem. I found that it was my test procedure who's returning the result using this 'WHERE e.modified_date >= '2013-04-02'::TIMESTAMP
AND e.modified_date <= '2013-04-02'::TIMESTAMP'. I was an idiot to call the test stored procedure instead of what is actually posted in my question.

Comment: Consider posting a useful explanation as an answer then, so others who find this later can learn from it. If you do, comment here and I'll upvote.

Comment: Hi Craig, an answer has been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column details:
`modified_date` : `TIMESTAMP`

Here's an actual values inserted in `modified_date` field

modified_date
timestamp without time zone

2013-04-02 14:05:45.8611
2013-04-02 14:09:14.5422

A brief explanation why the test procedure with the `WHERE` clause of

```
WHERE e.modified_date >= '2013-04-02'::TIMESTAMP 
AND e.modified_date <='2013-04-02'::TIMESTAMP
```

returns nothing:
- Casting the `String` value `'2013-04-02'` to a `TIMESTAMP` datatype will result to `'2013-04-02 00:00:00'`
- First, the `WHERE` clause validates if the field `modified_date` (Refer to values) is greater than or equal to `'2013-04-02 00:00:00'`; which on the other hand, will return as `false`
- Second, the `WHERE` clause validates of the field `modified_date` (Refer to values) less than or equal to `'2013-04-02 00:00:00'`; which will return as `false`

This explanation only shows that the `SELECT` statement will only return a value that corresponds to the `WHERE` clause if and only if the `modified_date` is exactly `'2013-04-02 00:00:00'`

As for this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE e.modified_date::DATE BETWEEN '2013-04-02'::DATE
AND '2013-04-02'::DATE
```

Casting both `modified_date` and the `String` value to a `DATE` datatype will result to the following values:
`modified_date` as `TIMESTAMP` = `'2013-04-02 14:05:45.8611'`
`modified_date` as `DATE` = `'2013-04-02'`
`modified_date` as `TIMESTAMP` = `'2013-04-02 14:09:14.5422'`
`modified_date` as `DATE` = `'2013-04-02'`
`String value` as `STRING` = `'2013-04-02'`
`String value` as `DATE` = `'2013-04-02'`
NOTE:
This can also be done without casting the `String` value to `DATE` datatype. Casting the `String` on my part was for my validation purposes.
To answer my question, with the `WHERE` clause of:

```
WHERE e.modified_date::DATE between '2013-04-02'::DATE
AND '2013-04-02'::DATE
```

doesn't return anything is just I was calling the test stored procedure that uses the wrong `WHERE` clause.